# mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (111). Flask app

Tags: python, mysql

I looked up that error and they say it has something to do with the bind-address, I commented that line and still get that error. Besides when I ping the server no packets are received. I do no know what else to do.

```
def create_app():     
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY = "***",
    DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get('****.cleardb.com'),
    DATABASE_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('***'),
    DATABASE_USER=os.environ.get('***'),
    DATABASE=os.environ.get('heroku_****'),     
  )
```

Comment: Are you running a MySQL database locally, or is it remote? What's the config (excluding username/password) you're using? There are a couple reasons a client might not be able to connect. You can try connecting to the database with your CLI or using a GUI database client to try to narrow down the error to something more specific.

Comment: I am a little bit newbie here so pardon me in advance if I do not exactly answer what you expected. I had my database locally and then I export it to herokus online. Host: us-cdbr-east-02.cleardb.com; database: heroku_ec53029ac676735. Im using clearDB on heroku. I found that this may happen due to the bind-address but I already changed that and I still get that error.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the remote Heroku database? Can you post some of your code in your question without revealing anything sensitive? For example, where are you setting the address? Where are you connecting to the database?

Comment: Assuming you're using https://github.com/brandenc40/flask_mysql_connector, you might need to set `app.config['MYSQL_HOST']` to `us-cdbr-east-02.cleardb.com` and `app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE']` to `heroku_ec53029ac676735`.

Comment: Yes, Im trying to connect to remote heroku cleardb. Here is the code of the configuration --> : `def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY = "***",
        DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get('us-cdbr-east-02.cleardb.com'),
        DATABASE_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('***'),
        DATABASE_USER=os.environ.get('***'),
        DATABASE=os.environ.get('heroku_ec53029ac676735'),
    )` I do not know why I cannot connect since when I was running locally I was able to login in and create a user in my app with no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: `os.environ.get()` will return the value of an environment variable, or an empty string if that environment variable is not set. What you want to do is set `DATABASE_HOST` to `****.cleardb.com`, but what your *code* is doing is setting `DATABASE_HOST` to nothing, because there are no environment variables named `****.cleardb.com` in your environment. Then, your client assumes that you want to use `localhost` (which is the address your computer uses for itself, you may also see `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0`).

There might be en environment variable named "DATABASE_HOST", or one with a different name whose *value* is `****.cleardb.com`*. Try `DATABASE_HOST='****.cleardb.com'` to see if it works, and then you can switch to using something like `os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST')` in your source, rather than hard-coding the Heroku address, and setting `DATABASE_HOST` locally on your machine to the Heroku address.

Try something like this, with your actual values, **without committing it to version control** (because that is a security risk) just to make sure you have the right values:

```
def create_app():     
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY = "***",
    DATABASE_HOST='****.cleardb.com',
    DATABASE_PASSWORD='***',
    DATABASE_USER='***',
    DATABASE='heroku_****',
  )
```

Once you've confirmed you can connect with the hard-coded variables, you should check to see if [Heroku's config/environment variables documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#local-setup) helps orient you. In Python, you access what they call "Config Vars" the same as what I've been calling "environment variables". The correct end state should be something like this:

1. You have a set of environment variables set on your local machine with the values you want to use. If you're using macOS/Linux/bash, this [documentation on how to read and write environment variables](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-linux) might help. These should have the same names Heroku is using, because you want them to get the right value when the environment (local or remote) is different. For the sake of this example, we'll give them all the prefix `HEROKU_`.
2. Your code uses `os.environ.get()` *and* the appropriate name of the *environment* variable to get that value, and it should get the correct value locally (when your local database is running) or remotely (when you're running in Heroku's cloud).

That would look like this, in theory:

```
def create_app():     
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_mapping(
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('HEROKU_SECRET_KEY'),
    DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get('HEROKU_DATABASE_HOST'),
    DATABASE_PASSWORD=os.environ.get('HEROKU_DATABASE_PASSWORD'),
    DATABASE_USER=os.environ.get('HEROKU_DATABASE_USER'),
    DATABASE=os.environ.get('HEROKU_DATABASE'),
  )
```

If I understand your comment correctly, it looks like you're setting Python variables to the values you want to use (like "`DATABASE_HOST='some.host-name.example.com'`"), then passing your app a mapping of configuration keys to values that you retrieve by asking the environment for variables with the names of the *values* you want to use, like this:

```
DATABASE_HOST='some.host-name.example.com'

def create_app():     
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_mapping(
    DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get(DATABASE_HOST),
  )
```

When your *Python* variable named `DATABASE_HOST` is set to the value of `'some.host-name.example.com'`, os.environ.get(DATABASE_HOST) is telling Python to get the *value* of a variable **named** "some.host-name.example.com", not "DATABASE_HOST", from the environment *outside* of your code. Do you see the difference? In one, you're passing a variable, which will resolve to a string, and Python will go look that up, find that you do *not* have an environment variable named "some.host-name.example.com", and return nothing.

If you have an *environment* variable named "DATABASE_HOST",  "HEROKU_DATABASE_HOST", or "DERF", you want to pass `os.environ.get()` a string which matches the *name* of your environment variable (so, `os.environ.get('DERF')` will return whatever the value of `DERF` is set to in the *environment* in which your code is running. To extend the above example, this would work, _provided that you have an environment variable named `DATABASE_HOST`. That environment variable is *outside of your code*:

```
ANY_VARIABLE_NAME_IT_DOESNT_MATTER='DATABASE_HOST'

def create_app():     
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_mapping(
    DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get(ANY_VARIABLE_NAME_IT_DOESNT_MATTER),
  )
```

Although there *might* be a good reason to do something similar to the above, you might as well just do this, which will be more legible:

```
def create_app():     
  app = Flask(__name__)
  app.config.from_mapping(
    DATABASE_HOST=os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST'),
    # notice the single quotes --^-------------^
  )
```

* use your **real**, unredacted hostname here.

Comment: Ok, but should I change that only on the host or on every database variable such as password, user and database name?

Comment: @Franco It depends, are they different? There are kinda two different issues here: first, that you're sending an empty value for one config, because of the way you're calling `os.environ.get()`. Second, environment variables can (and will) vary between environments (thus the name). They don't _have_ to vary. But if your username/password vary between the computer in front of you and the Heroku environment, yes. Heroku should have documentation about default environment variable _names_ you can use, and they'll handle switching the values in different environments.

Comment: @Franco More specifically, you shouldn't hard-code your credentials in your source. Using environment variables is 100% the way to go! I'm only suggesting hard-coding the database host as a way to confirm that's your only problem, then switching to use best practices (not hard-coding these values in your source).

Comment: I did as you told me, DATABASE_HOST='****.cleardb.com but when I tried to log in I got an error so I did that but with every database var and that is when I saw a chrome banner telling me that the site have been compromised and that I should change password right away.

Comment: Afterwards I did the following and got the same error as the beginning --> `DATABASE_HOST = '***.cleardb.com'
DATABASE_PASSWORD = '***'
DATABASE_USER = '***'
DATABASE = 'heroku_***'

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY= '***',
        DATABASE_HOST= os.environ.get(DATABASE_HOST),
        DATABASE_PASSWORD= os.environ.get(DATABASE_PASSWORD),
        DATABASE_USER= os.environ.get(DATABASE_USER),
        DATABASE= os.environ.get(DATABASE),
    )` What am I missing here? I hope you understood what Im trying to say

Comment: @Franco I expanded on my answer to clarify what I think is the mistake you're making: confusing environment variables with global Python variables.